# Keras target shape is incorrect

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am relatively new to keras so i played around with a simple seq2seq architecture.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(22, 10, input_length=32, mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim=3)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y,nb_epoch =1, batch_size = 1, verbose = 2)

Exception: Error when checking model target: expected activation_6 to have shape (None, 32, 3) but got array with shape (2, 4, 3)
```

x has shape of (2,32) and y has shape of (2,4,3).

According to my understanding, it means that y has 2 examples with each sequence have a length of 4 and one hot-encoded into 3 dimension. However, when i ran model.fit it seems its not the shape that i am expecting. Why is this so?

Comment: Your x needs to be 3 dimensional

Comment: But I placed it in an embedding layer